# I have Integers in an array that I need converted to strings

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, integer, irb

When I type

```
digicollect=[]
digicollect[0]=2
```

I get 2 when I type in digicollect in the irb.

Also, when I type in

```
"Hello" * 2
```

I get "HelloHello"

But if I type in

```
2 * "Hello"
```

it doesn't work.

```
"hello" * digicollect
```

doesn't work. 
but

```
"hello" * digicollect[0]
```

does work.

Why?

Comment: a very important tag is missing. which technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using command prompt, and irb inside of it. ruby version 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in ruby is an object, and even multiplications are just method calls.

`"Hello" * 2` is the same as `"Hello".*(2)`

So when you get an error you should ask yourself: Do the left hand side really have the multiplication method and will it accept the right hand side as an argument?

```
digicollect    = []
digicollect[0] = 2
```

Let us check what kind of objects we have:

```
p digicollect.class #=> Array
p digicollect[0].class #=> Fixnum
p 2.class #=> Fixnum
p "Hello".class #=> String
```

Now if we go into the docs for the *-method we find what each class expect:

```
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-2A
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-2A
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-2A
```

In there we find what will happen:

- String expects an Integer. (num of times to repeat string)
- Array expects an Integer or a String. (to repeat array x times or to join using string)
- Fixnum expects an Numeric. (For simple multiplication)

Thus when you write `"hello" * digicollect` you are trying to call the multiplication method of a sting and pass it an Array, and the method simply do not know how to handle it (it will only accept Integers), that is why you get the error.

Comment: I see. That's really useful thanks. Is there a way to see suggestions?

Comment: I'm slightly confused about what you typed "String excepts and Integer Array excepts an Integer or a String Fixnum expects an Numeric or Integer". By excepts do you mean accepts or expects?

Comment: Hope that clear things up. Really try to read the docs for each type and see what the *-method do for each class.

Answer (score 0):

I should preface this by saying I don't get `2` when I type `digicollect` in irb ... I get `[2]`.  This is a single element array with a value of 2.  That's very different from the integer value 2.

String has no `*` operator for an array argument, and number has no `*` operator with a string argument.  However, String does have `*` with a number argument, and `digicollect[0]` access the numeric value of that array element.

Comment: Ok thanks! So now I'm wondering why if I type "hello"*(digicollect[0]-5) it won't give me an answer, just "negative argument" ?

Comment: You can't multiply the string by a negative number.  If `digicollect[0]` is 2, for example, then you're subtracting 5, giving -3.

Answer (score -1):

digicollect itself is not numeric, that's why you can't 'multiply' by it.  It contains numbers, though, which is why "hello" * digicollect[0] works.

As for the 2 * "Hello" case, I believe that's a syntactic thing about the language - The string must come first and the integer second.